# How to match numbers within a word in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following scenario, I don't seem to solve this.

```
String = "a var a12nd with code is on467th";
```

in the above string i am required to match words with numbers in it and matches the numbers in another group, can you please help?

**expected output:**

```
match1:  a12nd 
group1: 12

mach2: on467th
group1:467
```

Comment: What do want to do with: `abc123`, `123abc` and `a1b2c`?

Comment: i have to capture them too.

Comment: You can't select in an uniq group digits that are not contiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, it matches any letter followed by any number followed by any letter and it is storing number in a group.

it also maches if a number is at the start and end of the word

```
([a-z]*([\d]+)[a-z]*)
```

[try demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cllZpo/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
[a-z]+(\d+)[a-z]+
```

This translates to match :

```
Any white space followed by alphabets followed by a number (you want) followed by alphabets.
```

Here `group 1` would be your number and `group 0` would be the string containing the number.

[See this in action](https://regex101.com/r/y1QEbb/3).

Comment: it is also matching space.